# Why can't I type in my search bar of my Ubuntu app?

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, youtube

I am following a YouTube tutorial (here: [Creating Your First Ubuntu App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg)) for creating my own Ubuntu app.

However, when I get to the part where I add a text bar, I save to then run and try to type in text, but nothing happens.

Please tell me there is an easy solution to this.

Comment: Just to clarify.  Is the problem that you can't type into the box (no text gets shown) or that when you do you can't do anything with it?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work.

However in glade select the text box and look on the general tab.

If you set "Editable" to no then you won't be able to type.  Check this setting as shown below

[image: Glade]